# PHPexcel check if column value made by recipe

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I 'm using ms excel to upload large data to my system. When I upload excel file which has columns made by recipe.The uploading progess is longer than usual.Now,I want to check valid the input excel file.If they have columns made by recipe, the system will cancel progess. I 've read phpexcel doucment, but not found any solution.
Do you have any ideas?
My source

My source:
   $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

```
                $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($uploaded_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $new_name);
                $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

                $highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
                $total_order_row = $highestRow;

                $highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'
                $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn); // e.g. 5
```

for ($i = 1; $i <= $highestRow; $i++) {
                        $data1 = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $i)->getValue();

```
                    $data2= $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $i)->getValue();

                    $data3= $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $i)->getValue();
                    //Todo: insert to db

                }
```

Comment: "Do you have any ideas?" without code, no.

Answer (score 0):

If "by recipe" you mean by a calculation, then check the datatype of a cell rather than the value:

```
if ($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $i)->getDataType() == PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_FORMULA) {
    echo 'I contain a formula; use getCalculatedValue() to get my value';
}
```